# Show bootstrap panel in a row inside foreach loop

Tags: c#, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-5

Here is my code, what should I do to show 3 panels in a row. Is there any way to do this?

Its showing in the same row but the next panel starts slightly below the previous one I'll be really thankful to you for your help

```
@foreach (DEProperty.Web.Models.PlotsViewModelSearchResult c in Model)
{                       
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="panel panel-info">
        <div class="panel-heading text-center">
            <h4>@c.PhaseText, @c.SectorText-@c.PlotAddress</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body text-center">
            <p class="lead">
                <img src="~/images/plot...image.jpg" />

            </p>
        </div>
        <ul class="list-group list-group-flush text-center">
            <li class="list-group-item" style="border:none">
                @c.AreaText
              </li>
            <li class="list-group-item" style="border:none">
                Facing Park
              </li>
            <li class="list-group-item text-center" style="border:none">
                Near Mosque
            </li>
            <li class="list-group-item" style="border:none">
                Near Commercial
            </li>
            <li class="list-group-item" style="border:none">
                Corner
            </li>

        </ul>
        <div class="panel-footer">
            <a class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-info">Detail View</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Add `<div class="row">` like this:

```
 <div class="row">    
 @foreach (DEProperty.Web.Models.PlotsViewModelSearchResult c in Model)
 {
    ....
 }
 </div>
```

Comment: this will render each panel on separate row. The OP wants panels on same row.